# What is happening during queue_free() process?

Tags: godot, memory, gdscript

From time to time, I encounter a hard-to-reproduce bug with a similar line of code:

```
## File: Level.gd

func _on_player_invisible() -> void:
    player.queue_free()
```

which sometimes crashes with: *Attempt to call `queue_free` in base `null instance` on a null instance*

---

I have added this null check condition, but the crash can still be observed:

```
## File: Level.gd

func _on_player_invisible() -> void:
    if player: player.queue_free()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reproducing the error

I managed to reproduce this reliably. It happens when calling `queue_free` on a `Node` that has already been freed (but the reference is not actually null, the error message is misleading).

This code should produce the error:

```
player.queue_free()
yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
player.queue_free()
```

For the error to happen, it is necessary and sufficient that a frame happens between both calls of `queue_free`. If multiple calls of `queue_free` happen in the same frame, there is no error. Multiple frames happening between the calls of `queue_free` do not prevent the error.

---

### Observed behaviour

Before calling `queue_free` for the first time, we observe:

```
print(player == null)                  # false
print(!is_instance_valid(player))      # false
print(player.is_queued_for_deletion()) # false
```

After calling `queue_free`, we observe:

```
print(player == null)                  # false
print(!is_instance_valid(player))      # false
print(player.is_queued_for_deletion()) # true
```

After a frame passes (and thus the `Node` has been freed), we observe:

```
print(player == null)                  # false
print(!is_instance_valid(player))      # true
print(player.is_queued_for_deletion()) # ERROR
```

The error is: `"Attempt to call function 'is_queued_for_deletion' in base 'null instance' on a null instance."` (notice that it isn't actually null, instead it has been freed). *As a consequence `is_queued_for_deletion` is not a good filter by itself.*

For reference, if we call `is_queued_for_deletion` on null, we get: `"Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'is_queued_for_deletion' in base 'Nil'."`.

Finally, if we attempt to call `queue_free` again, we get the error you saw: `"Attempt to call function 'queue_free' in base 'null instance' on a null instance."`.

---

**Addendum on Nil vs Null**: One of the possible types a `Variant` can have is `Nil`, which by definition is `null`. This is what you get if you write `null` on GDScript (A `Variant` of type `Nil`). However a "null instance" is not of type `Nil`. Instead you get "null instance" when you have an invalid pointer. Thus, C++ methods which do not return `Variant` but can return an invalid pointer will not give you `Nil` (For example `get_node_or_null`) and if they give you an invalid pointer, and you try to use it you get the "null instance" error. The same error you get with `queue_free` as explained in this answer (after the `Node` is freed, any pointers to it are now invalid).

---

### Preventing the error

Therefore to prevent the error when the code can call `queue_free` multiple times, we want to avoid calling it when a frame has passed since the last call. That is, we want to avoid calling it when `is_instance_valid(...)` is false. In other words, we only call it when `is_instance_valid(...)` is true:

```
if is_instance_valid(player):
    player.queue_free()
```

Note that `is_instance_valid(null)` is also false. So we don't need to check for null.

Thus, checking `is_instance_valid(...)` is both necessary and sufficient to prevent the error. We could check for `is_queued_for_deletion` also to make sure that `queue_free` is only ever called once (although this is not necessary to prevent the error).

---

### How `queue_free` works, looking at the source code

Looking at the source for `queue_free`, the first thing we find is that it actually binds to the method `queue_delete` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/node.cpp#L2864)). Which looks like this ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/scene_tree.cpp#L1124)):

```
void SceneTree::queue_delete(Object *p_object) {

    _THREAD_SAFE_METHOD_
    ERR_FAIL_NULL(p_object);
    p_object->_is_queued_for_deletion = true;
    delete_queue.push_back(p_object->get_instance_id());
}
```

*That null check produces a different error ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/error_macros.h#L261)).*

There you can see where `_is_queued_for_deletion` is set to true, which we check with `is_queued_for_deletion()`.

Note that no check is done on whether or not this is called multiple times.

As per the process that actually frees the Node, it is in `_flush_delete_queue` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/scene_tree.cpp#L1110)). It consumes the queue, and calls `memdelete` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/os/memory.h#L112)).

The method `memdelete` calls the "predelete handler" for the object if it has one, then the destructor and finally releases the memory. It is likely that there is a "predelete handler" as the `Object` class has one ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/object.cpp#L384)) that sends the `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE`. Which the `Node` class handles ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/node.cpp#L156)) by setting its `owner` to null, removing itself from its parent, and then removing all the children and calling `memdelete` on them.

Finally, it is the destructor of the `Object` class ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/object.cpp#L1995)) the one that disconnect signals connect from it, then disconnects the signals connected to it. Then removes the instance from the object database… Which is what `is_instance_valid` checks.

Comment: Is it worth to report an issue and ask for a more relevant error message?

Comment: @pietrodito I'd go with yes open it, and let the dev decide if it is worth fixing, and how.  It appears it remains the same in Godot 4.0 (so far), I haven't found where the error text is in the 3.3 branch (In my defense Github only searches the default branch). Note: You will get this error if using the result of `get_node_or_null` on a non existing node path. Which is likely how most people will encounter it, and what most search results will point you to if you search for it.