# deleting and re-referencing nodes with $

Tags: godot, instancing, gdscript

I want to delete a scene and re-load it. This code would fail later, because the new "CoolScene" has in fact a different name, something like "@NotSuchCoolName@34", and thus it cannot be referenced with $CoolScene once the garbage collector destroys the old scene:

```
$CoolScene.queue_free()
var cool_node = load("res://pathto/CoolScene.tscn").instance()
add_child(cool_node )
cool_node.set_name("CoolScene")
```

But if I rename the scene, then it will work:

```
$CoolScene.set_name("oldCoolScenebyebye")
$oldCoolScenebyebye.queue_free()
var cool_node = load("res://pathto/CoolScene.tscn").instance()
add_child(cool_node)
cool_node.set_name("CoolScene")


$CoolScene.whatever #Works now!
```

However this looks like awful code to me, main reason being that I need to invent temp names that are unique everytime a scene gets deleted, something that should be done by the garbage collector. Please help me write better code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look that this code:

```
$CoolScene.queue_free()
var cool_node = load("res://pathto/CoolScene.tscn").instance()
add_child(cool_node)
cool_node.set_name("CoolScene")
```

The first line `$CoolScene.queue_free()` will delete the `Node` referenced by `$CoolScene`. But not yet. *See also [What is happening during queue_free() process?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/192362/10408)* - Suffice to say that Godot will remove the `Node` from the scene tree, and free it sometime after the code finished executing, and no, that isn't a garbage collector.

The second and third line instantiates and adds a new child `Node`. Be aware that at this point, this new `Node` will already have a name. Godot would have generated a new name if it collided with the name of the existing `Node`.

And finally the fourth line would change the name of the `Node`. Except it still cannot have that name because the existing node still has it.

---

To fix that we are going to separate removing a `Node` from the scene tree and freeing it.

```
var old_node = $CoolScene
remove_child(old_node)

var cool_node = load("res://pathto/CoolScene.tscn").instance()
add_child(cool_node)

old_node.queue_free()
```

Here the first line `var old_node = $CoolScene` is keeping a reference to the old node in a variable so I can call `queue_free` on it at the end.

The second line `remove_child(old_node)` removes it from the scene tree.

Now the third and fourth lines can instantiate and add the new node. Which can have its expected name - right away (we didn't have to wait until the old `Node` was freed) and without issue - since the old node is not in the scene tree anymore.

Finally the fifth line calls `queue_free` on the old node, which can be deleted sometime later also with no issue.

*And, of course, we didn't have to come up with some other name.*

Comment: Thank you, I should have thought about that as well! Very well explained too